# AWX docker-compose stop not working

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-compose, ansible-tower

I'm pretty new to docker-compose and I can't seem to make this work. I have been following [this](https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/INSTALL.md#docker-or-docker-compose) guide for installing AWX and has been successful so far.

But when trying to stop everything using docker-compose as instructed in the document, I am only getting these warnings, and the containers are not stopping.

```
WARNING: The CURRENT_UID variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The DEV_DOCKER_TAG_BASE variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The TAG variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

I am guessing I need to set these variables in the docker-compose.yml file, but I can't figure out what should these be.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the installer/inventory file and enable docker-compose:

```
use_docker_compose=true
```

Set the location of the docker-compose file accordingly. By default, it's

```
docker_compose_dir=/var/lib/awx
```

Once the installation is completed, you should see the `docker-compose.yml` file in `/var/lib/awx`.

Cheers.